# Использование сторонних шрифтов через папку Font

Tags: java, android, шрифты

Создал папку Font. Положил в нее шрифт. Выбрал свой TextView и указал fontFamaly мой шрифт. В предпросмоторщике все работает. Пытаюсь запустить на эмуляторе приложение:

```
Process 'command 'C:\Users\ROCKer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

minSdk 16

compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion 26

p.s. я знаю как указать использование стороннего шрифта для определенного элемента через `Typeface`. задача стоить подключить этот шрифт для всего приложения через `styles.xml` и `<item name="android:fontFamily">`. но, конечно же, это не работает, т.к. шрифт из папки Font не может даже установиться на определенный элемент. куда ему до всего приложения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что нашел следующий выход. Приложение не создается из-за обращения к папки Font (почему? не знаю).

Я создал папку res/raw и положил туда свой шрифт font.otf

В styles.xml задал `<item name="android:fontFamily">@raw/font</item>`

На API 19 все работает почти идеально (заголовок AlertDialog не меняется). На API 26 AlertDialog вообще не принимается шрифт. Поэтом написал следующее:

```
 public static void applyCustomFontToDialog(Context context, Dialog dialog) {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") Typeface font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.raw.font);
        if (font != null) {
// должен быть именно import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
            TextView titleView = dialog.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.alertTitle);
            TextView messageView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            if (titleView != null) titleView.setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD);
            if (messageView != null) messageView.setTypeface(font);
        }
    }
```

теперь, когда создаю диалог-окно

```
alrt.show();
applyCustomFontToDialog(this, alrt);
```

Но встал другой вопрос:

styles.xml `<item name="android:fontFamily">@raw/font</item>`

это работает от API 16. я сделал тест при `gradle: minSdkVersion 14` - все работает.

Вопрос: что будет на телефоне с API 14? шрифт просто не применится или приложение вообще не запуститься?

Comment: почему бы вам не использовать кастомный textview с attr? где вы будете брать шрифт из папки assets. Таким образом можно и переопределить весь шрифт в приложении на шрифт из этой папки

Comment: @Сергей да, я видел этот метод. но, на мой взгляд, мой способ проще.